# How to use scrollView functions with AsyncDisplayKit

Tags: ios, swift, collectionview, asyncdisplaykit

I have this function I use on my collection view:

```
func scrollViewWillEndDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>){
}
```

It doesn't seem to work now that I have converted over to using AsyncDisplayKit.  The collection view is not an ASCollectionView and that function doesn't give any errors but it just doesn't work now.  In the docs I read about scrollNode but I'm not sure if that replaces scrollview.  It sounds more like it wraps around it so I don't see why scrollView can no longer be accessed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I figured it out and it was really simple.  All I had to do was make it an asyncDelegate like this:

```
collectionView.asyncDelegate = self
```

So I feel kind of dumb because this is as simple as making it a UICollectionViewDelegate.  I guess I just didn't realize that I hadn't done that yet or else I would have had an error when converting it from UICollectionView to ASCollectionView and just changed it.